# How to save the file content in python?

Tags: python, file, matrix, python-2.7

I just started to work on `python` and it's a very basic question:

I have a `input.txt` which contains following test cases:

```
b---d
-d--d
--dd-
--d--
----d
```

Now i want to save the above content in `5 X 5`  `Matrix` with the help of python code. So that when i want to return `matrix[0][2]` It returns `-`.

How should i do that?
I tried it but it prints wrong answer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you want to learn more, it's always a good idea to also post your code (which is now giving you the wrong result). That would allow us to show you *why* it's not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very easy, as strings and files are iterables too:

```
with open('input.txt') as matrixfile:
    matrix = [list(line.strip()) for line in matrixfile]
```

`list()` on a string turns it into a list of the individual characters; we use `.strip()` to remove any extra whitespace, including the newline. The `matrixfile` open file object is an iterable, so we can loop over it to process all the lines.

Result:

```
>>> matrix
[['b', '-', '-', '-', 'd'], ['-', 'd', '-', '-', 'd'], ['-', '-', 'd', 'd', '-'], ['-', '-', 'd', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-', '-', 'd']]
>>> matrix[0][2]
'-'
```

Comment: Fastest gun in the west :)

Answer (score 2):

So since Martijn was faster in posting the obvious answer, here's another idea:

You actually don't need to create a nested list ("matrix") at all:

```
with open("input.txt") as infile:
    matrix = [line.rstrip() for line in infile]
```

gives you a list of five strings which can be indexed (and will return a single character when done so) just like the nested list can:

```
>>> matrix
['b---d', '-d--d', '--dd-', '--d--', '----d']
>>> matrix[0][2]
'-'
```